# Returning reference using a ternery expression causes runtime error

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

For some reason, the second method will not work.

```
concurrency::event<void( event_data& ), codec_cvt> &get_event( const string_type &event )
{
        auto it = events_.find( event );
        if ( it == events_.end( ) )
            throw /* exception */;
        return *it->second;
}
```

However, this method using my preffered syntax is returning an address of a temporary. When it should be exactly, correct?

```
concurrency::event<void( event_data& ), codec_cvt> &get_event( const string_type &event )
{
    auto it = events_.find( event );
    return it != events_.end( ) ?
        *it->second :
        throw;
 }
```

Comment: Even if the ternary operator converts its operand to an rvalue, I can't see how an rvalue could get converted to an lvalue reference. There's explicit clause for a ternary operator with one of the expression being a `throw`, and I find nothing there that specifies that the other expression becomes an rvalue. Perhaps you should explain why you believe you're getting a temporary object constructed here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The compiler is litterally telling me it. https://i.gyazo.com/a86d702474ab21ca2eb37e3e0be7a4f5.png

Comment: Firstly, you should paste the text of the error message, instead of a screen dump. Secondly, a little bit of experimentation with gcc indicates that if both ternary expressions are lvalues, an lvalue can be returned. If one of them is `throw`, even if the other one is an lvalue it appears to be converted to an rvalue, and an lvalue cannot be returned. I don't immediately see why, according to the specification, but this must be the answer. Well, that answers that.

Comment: I just prefer screenshots when I'm unable to copy the text, writing out manually would be a pain. And yeah, that does seem to be the problem.

Comment: This is [core issue 1560](http://wg21.link/cwg1560), and it appears that MSVC hasn't gotten around to implementing its resolution yet.

Comment: The first version is more natural to read anyway, IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++14, the standard provided that the result of an expression of the form `false ? throw 1 : x` is a copy of `x` rather than `x` itself (technically, it applies the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer conversions on `x` to yield a prvalue). [N3337 [expr.cond]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.cond#2):

> If either the second or the third operand has type `void`, then the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue ([conv.lval]), array-to-pointer ([conv.array]), and
>   function-to-pointer ([conv.func]) standard conversions are performed
>   on the second and third operands, and one of the following shall hold:
>
> - The second or the third operand (but not both) is a *throw-expression* ([except.throw]); the result is of the type of the other and is a prvalue.
> - [...]

This was changed by [Core issue 1560](http://wg21.link/CWG1560):

> A glvalue appearing as one operand of a conditional-expression in
>   which the other operand is a throw-expression is converted to a
>   prvalue, regardless of how the conditional-expression is used:
>
> [...]
>
> This seems to be gratuitous and surprising.

and the paragraph [now reads](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.cond#2):

> If either the second or the third operand has type `void`, one of the
>   following shall hold:
>
> - The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) *throw-expression* ([expr.throw]); the result is of the
>     type and value category of the other. The *conditional-expression* is
>     a bit-field if that operand is a bit-field.
> - [...]

MSVC simply hasn't gotten around to implementing the fix yet. Clang 3.5+ does have it implemented.